# UDP packet: How to send different datatypes in one packet?

Tags: java, udp

I am programming a multiplayer game and I am having a hard time with the size of udp packets. I want to send multiple enemy stats (hp, position, id) via udp packets. Here is the important code-part:

```
Byte[] datagramPacketData = ("11" + String.valueOf(entityAmount) + "," + gamename + "," + username + entitiesToBeSent).getBytes();
```

As you can see, i am merging all the data into a String and then convert it to byte[] before i send it. But chars consume much more bytes than little ints(for id and position) and longs(hp).
For example: one mob has 2.000.000 hp. that number will consume 7 chars(=7 byte), but it would only need 4 byte for long. how can i send all this data by using up less bytes, without using object streams?

I would be very happy about some suggestions!
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Convert each individual chunk to bytes instead of converting them to strings and then all to bytes at once?

Comment: how do you parse them on the receiving side then? I mean, how can i know which chunk of bytes is what. Because i will receive only one byte[] mesh

Comment: There are several things you could do. You could make a standard length packet so ranges of positions in the byte array correspond to certain variables consistently, or you could append bytes to the array telling you the position of the start of each variable, etc.

Comment: ahh good idea! :) i think ill stick to your first suggestion. Thank you very much, i think i can solve this now :) take care friend!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, provided that your data is small enough to fit into a single packet, the UDP message length is unlikely to make much difference.  I would recommend that you don't sweat on the issue unless you have concrete evidence that packet size is a critical issue; i.e. hard benchmarking results that show that you won't be able to sustain the minimum transmission rate required by the game above a certain packet size.  (Optimizing for a problem that doesn't actually exist is a waste of effort.)

If you are concerned about message length, then you should compare using string encoding (as above) and binary encoding; e.g. like you would get using `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream`.

- a `byte` will be encoded as a single octet
- a `short` or `char` will be encoded as two octets
- etc.

See the `DataOutputStream` [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) for details.

Don't use object streams.  They use the same binary encoding as `DataOutputStream`, but there are significant additional overheads for encoding type information and object identities.

Comment: thank you! :) I will go from string encoding to binary encoding, that should solve my concern! :)

Comment: But first check that your concern is well-founded.  If it isn't then your change will make little difference.  It will be a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

I have made my attempt now and it works for String, but not or long. I cant figure out the mistake on my own, mayb eone of you can find the error?
Here is it:

On sender side:

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int i = 0;

        String packetNumber = "25";

        ByteBuffer buffer0 = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
        buffer0.put(packetNumber.getBytes());
        byte[] numberInByte = buffer0.array();

        int x = 0;
        for (int k = i; k < numberInByte.length; k++) {
            data[k] = numberInByte[x];
            x++;
            i++;
        }

        long life = 2000000;

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
        buffer.putLong(life);
        byte[] lifeInByte = buffer.array();

        x = 0;
        for (int k = i; k < lifeInByte.length; k++) {
            data[k] = lifeInByte[x];
            x++;
            i++;
        }
```

On receiver side:

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);

        byte[] packetNumber = new byte[2];
        byteBuffer.get(packetNumber);
        System.out.println(new String(packetNumber));

        long life = byteBuffer.getLong();
        System.out.println(life);
```

The output is:
25 (which is right)
1966080 (which is not quite 2000000, but why?)

Comment: Use DataOutputStream + ByteArrayOutputStream, etc.  It is simpler.